# Sencha Touch: List ItemTap Event Firing

Tags: javascript, oop, extjs, sencha-touch

I am following along very closely with the code within the [GeoCongress.us App](http://geocongress.us/app/), as this is my first Sencha Touch app and the premise behind that app's layout functionality is similar to what I hope to achieve.

I am having an issue getting a List object to respond to the `itemtap` event though. My intent is to capture the `itemtap` event at the `SetsScreen` level, fire my own custom event which my `App` object would listen for, and `App` could then handle the process of displaying a new card (based on the item tapped).

First, the `SetsScreen` object (relevant portions of it at least):

```
DataSets.views.SetsScreen = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    cls: 'sets-screen',
    layout: 'card',

    initComponent: function() { 
        // Build the main content list and add it to the main scren
        this.setsList = new DataSets.views.SetsList({
            scroll: false
        });
        this.setsList.on('itemtap', this.onListItemTap, this);

        this.main = new Ext.Container({
            scroll: true,
            items: [this.setsList]
        });

        this.items = [this.main];
        DataSets.views.SetsScreen.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },

    onListItemTap: function(dv, index, item, e) {
        alert('Test');
    }
});
```

Here is my `SetsList` object (nothing really amazing here):

```
DataSets.views.SetsList = Ext.extend(Ext.List, {
    itemSelector: '.sets-list-item',
    singleSelect: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = DataSets.stores.Sets;
        this.itemTpl = Ext.XTemplate.from('sets-list');

        DataSets.views.SetsList.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

And the `Sets` object is nothing more than a quick data model and Ext.data.Store:

```
Ext.regModel('Sets', {
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        'title',
        'last_updated',
        'current_value'
    ]
});

DataSets.stores.Sets = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Sets',
    data: [
        {id: 0, title: 'Weight', last_updated: new Date('11/28/2010 00:00:00 AM GMT-0600'), current_value: 145},
        {id: 1, title: 'Cups of Coffee', last_updated: new Date('11/28/2010 07:00:00 AM GMT-0600'), current_value: 1}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man - I don't know how I stumbled across this answer, a very obscure typo was the only thing preventing this from working.

`Ext.List()` uses it's `itemSelector` property to determine what element qualified for a "tap". My `itemSelector` was set to `.sets-list-item` but the template had `<div class="set-list-item">`. Correcting the template and `itemtap` is firing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look at the [updated screencast](http://media.vimcasts.org/videos/tmp/GeoTweets-revised.mov) - since some of the API's changed in the 1.0 release and the older screencast is now out of synch.

Comment: Never even saw the screencasts - thanks for the link! This is in reference to GeoTweets (not GeoCongress, which I am using to learn from) but I'm going to watch it anyway for clues. Nonetheless, I am referencing the valid 1.0 API documentation and nothing is standing out.

Comment: Or is it now out of "syncha"?